# Ubuntu kernel 5.8.0-36-generic full of problems latest nvidia upgrades brake older kernels 5.4.0-60/58-generic

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, kernel

There are hard problems with the new updates on 20.04.1-LTS:

1. Kernel 5.8.0-36-generic lacks lots of drivers (mostly network
   (ethernet/wifi)).
2. New NVIDIA drivers brake old kernels (5.4.0) and even in 5.8.0-36 aren´t working properly:

   2.1) In a Predator Helios only the HDMI port renders plasma (X11)
   2.2) In the same computer the native display is not detected by X11
   2.3) In old kernel the NVIDIA driver is not installed by kmod daemon

Please, in LTS check things before putting them into production...

Comment: This site is not actually part of the Ubuntu development/release team, although I share some of your pain.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question

Comment: If it's a problem and not a question, I strongly recommend you file bugs. `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reported as a bug here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.8/+bug/1911136

A work-around might be to reboot with the working 5.4 kernel.

Comment: Kernel 5.4.0-60 will work except that NVIDIA drivers and applications won´t be available (and I´m a strong CUDA user). Even if I downgrade driver to 455 instead of the 460 the driver won´t load anymore and I´d have to pick all NVIDIA stuff back to 455. An alternative would be to remove the NVIDIA stuff installed by apt, download everything from NVIDIA site and install everything  by hand.

Comment: Kernel 5.4.0-58 won´t even start graphical interface.

Comment: It shoud fallback to the Nouveau driver.. Maybe you need to boot into recovery mode?

Comment: kernel 5.8.0-34 does work for me